# .htaccess Redirect except for Root of a single domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Assuming I have three domains: domain1.tld, domain2.tld and domain3.tld

All request should redirect to newdomain.tld/new except for the root of domain1.tld.
But unfortunately my exception is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.tld$
RewriteRule ^/$ https://newdomain.tld/new [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain1\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.tld/new [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule would seem to perform the specific redirect you are trying to prevent, if it wasn't for the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^/$`, which will never match, so the first rule doesn't actually do anything.

The second rule doesn't redirect any requests to `domain1.tld`, so again, `domain1.tld/` is not redirected by the second rule either.

Make sure you are not seeing a cached response. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser, so always test with a 302 first to avoid potential caching issues.

A couple of additional assumptions:

- `newdomain.tld` points to a different server.
- You do not need to serve any static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc) from the page at `domain1.tld/` - since these will be redirected to `newdomain.tld`. The exception is literally only for requests to the document root.

Try it like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exception for "domain1.tld/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

# Everything else redirects to "newdomain.tld/new"
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.tld/new [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against the URL-path, less the slash prefix. ie. `^$` (an *empty* URL-path) matches the root. (You would only use `^/$` in a server context.)

NB: You will need to clear your browser cache before testing and test with a 302 first.